# "Protest" x "Complain"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can the verb "to protest" be used with the meaning of "to complain" in colloquial situations like these, or would it sound too formal and inappropriate?

You know he's been a more dedicated intern than you, so if he's chosen to earn the promotion you've been wanting, just promise that you'll do your best to be kind, compliment him, **and not protest**.

If your sister gets a more expensive gift than you this Christmas, just remember that you got a new car for your birthday. Try to be a good boy, accept whatever you get with a good heart **and not protest**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protest generally refers to demonstrating in the streets to promote a political cause or change. Complain would work better here.